# Split a string like 'foo=bar#baz=qo\#ox#al\=pha=beta using regexp

Tags: regex

Here's a quick challenge. 
Take this string `foo=bar#baz=qo\#ox#al\=pha=beta` which consists of  key-value pairs delimited by # from each other [pair] and with = as delimiter between key and value and split it into its components using regular expression (perl, python, classic, whatever). If characters # and = are encountered in the keys or values, they are prefixed with \. 
So, the result should be  a table of keys/values:

```
KEY    | VALUE
foo    |  bar
baz    | qo#ox
al=pha | beta
```

You get 100 points if your regexp (split or match) just splits it at the # character. Collect extra 50 points if you manage to split in one go also keys and values at = character.

P.S. it is trivial to solve this using token parsing and look-ahead or behind, so no points.

Answer (score 6):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use v5.10;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $input = 'foo=bar#baz=qo\#ox#al\=pha=beta';
my %table = $input =~ m'((?:\\.|[^\\=])+)=((?:\\.|[^\\#])+)#?'g;

for my $key (sort keys %table) { say "$key\t| $table{$key}" }
```

(EDIT: use single quotes on regexp, mostly to keep StackOverflow from thinking that # is a comment character).

Comment: The expression: `'((?:\\.|[^\\=])+)=((?:\\.|[^\\#])+)#?'` can be made more efficient by applying Friedl's _"Unrolling-the-Loop"_ technique like so: `([^\\=]*(?:\\.[^\\=]*)*)=([^\\#]*(?:\\.[^\\#]*)*)#?`. Otherwise good answer +1

Comment: @LHMathies I don't know perl , so I am not sure what is the meaning of ``\\`` in ``(?:\\`` and its meaning in ``[^\\=]`` . Does it mean the character ``'\'`` or the escaping symbol ? By the way, your expression is so evident after having seen it, but it's a tricky one.

Comment: @ridgerunner Fine reference to Friedl, I didn't know his _Unrolling the Loop_ technique, and for the moment I don't understand it, I haven't studied it yet. Still a lot of things to learn in regexes for me

Comment: @ridgerunner I didn't want to make the thing even more difficult to understand... besides, it's not strictly equivalent, since I had `+` in there instead of `*`. (The question doesn't say if empty keys or values are allowed). Also, the nested `*`s in the unrolling give me the creeps, it's hard to keep in mind that it's more efficient because of the unique matching of the start.

Comment: @Konrads Thanks for the points! Where do they show up, or what can I spend them on?

Comment: @eyquem In Perl, regexp parsing is not the same as the languages (PHP for instance) where you first have a string literal syntax with specific quoting conventions, and then a regexp parser with another layer of quoting. Most of the processing of a regexp pattern is the same as a quoted string of the same type, but the _escaping_ function of `\ ` is left to the regexp parsing stage. Therefore, `\\ ` is actually a single literal character. (Javascript has regular expression literals, and the same applies there).

Answer (score 0):

It's a two-step process:

1. Split @ '#' to get a list of key/value pairs
2. Loop over key/value pair strings and split at '='; put tokens into dictionary or map.

Comment: Apparently it can be done in one step as @LHmathies has proven :)

Answer (score 0):

In Python:

```
import re

string = "foo=bar#baz=qo\#ox#al\=pha=beta"

regx = re.compile('(?:(?<=\A)|(?<=#))((?:[^=]|(?<=\\\\)=)+)=((?:[^#]|(?<=\\\\)#)+)')

print regx.findall(string)
```

result

```
[('foo', 'bar'), ('baz', 'qo\\#ox'), ('al\\=pha', 'beta')]
```

.

EDIT

Answer with no interest: it doesn't respect the conditions expressed in the wording